# How to allow resource mp3 to continue playing even when phone screen switches off

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a resource file that plays upon a certain event, when a certain activity is called. (**All done through code**). Is there a way to ensure it continues playing even when the phone screen  turns off?

I guess one way to do this is to *programmatically* disable screen  off when the activity is triggered, but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Downvoters, please justify your downvotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service and start it in your activity.

```
public class serv extends Service{

    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    public void onCreate()
    {   
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audiofile);
        mp.setLooping(false);
    }
    public void onDestroy()
    {       
        mp.stop();
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent,int startid){

        Log.d(tag, "On start");
        mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me